# Avoid falling off edge

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a simple FPS game in Unity3d where a character cannot fall off the platform unless they jump off of it, walking off should be impossible. 
I made a script for objects that are on a moving platform:

```
public GameObject Player;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject == Player)
    {
        Player.transform.parent = transform;
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject == Player)
    {
        Player.transform.parent = null;
    }
}
```

And the only way I came up with to solve this problem is to create a short, invisible box collider working as a threshold, but adding it to every edge of every walking space would be a nightmare. Also I can't use nav mesh for it.

Comment: You could do a physics raycast to see whether there's a platform in the direction the player is about to move, and if not, restrict the movement.

Comment: And how would I do that?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

Answer (score 1):

Raycasting just in front of the player pointing down and seeing if it hits the level would be one option, however it's very expensive to run this a lot.

If your level is square (other shapes will work but will require some maths), you can take note of the top left and bottom right points as your boundary points and check if your players position + walking speed per frame would be outside this boundary square. If it is, deny the move.

E.g

```
if((transform.position + transform.forward * walkingSpeed * time.deltatime).x > maxX || < minX || .y > maxY || .y << minY)
    //Deny the move
```

Answer (score 1):

In the same way that you use colliders to detect the ground to allow / disallow jumping, you can also use colliders to detect edges of platforms.

Add a small collider to each corner or midpoint of each side of the bottom of your player object. The player can only move in directionA if the colliders on sideA of the player are in contact with the ground. This means that as you approach a ledge, the nearest side to the ledge will lose contact with the ground, therefore preventing any more movement in that direction.

If player is jumping, then allow movement in all directions regardless of collider contact.

You will have to play around with the position of these colliders and which directions you allow movement, but this seems like a simple yet effective approach to me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a prefab for the edges, everywhere there is an edge place the prefab so that the prefab is really the edge.  This will ensure that the code that works is always present on an edge.